# Undo changes to SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, recovery

I've ran some "ALTER" scripts on the database [SQL Server Server 2005], and overwrote some sprocs. Is there any way to undo changes and get my old sprocs back?

Is there a way to get the scripts that were executed out of the .LDf file? That way i can re-run my initial "create" script for my sprocs.

I don't have a backup file with old sprocs.

p.s. i backed the DB up as per [@Gulzar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4337/gulzar) deleted answer, and looks like I'm "hosed".

@Pittsburgh DBA: thanx for the solution, but it doesn't seem to work after the backup.

**MORAL: Wait for 10 minutes before trying the suggested answers out**

---

**Update from Gulzar**: What I meant was a file backup before trying anything (to be safe). Not a SQL Server backup.

Comment: Well, I reserved commenting further on the matter until I had a chance to see if there was some odd new feature of which I was somehow not aware.

What happened to you is explained in greater detail.

Here: http://blogs.msdn.com/arvindsh/archive/2007/06/15/the-role-of-stopat-in-restore-database.aspx

Comment: first of all, i am really sorry. it was something i tried out and looks like it worked. usually, if i wanted to try something especially from suggestions in forums, i would have done it on a copy. i was thinking you would be doing the same. sorry again.

Comment: @Mitch - you are right. SO reputation isn't everything. I have never said anywhere I am an expert. The bulk of my points is in helping people with simpler problems.:) This episode has taught me to be very careful from now onwards.

Comment: by backup, I meant a file backup. Not a SQL server backup.

Comment: c'mon ... who cares now? it's all good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FIRST: DO NOT TAKE ANY BACKUPS JUST YET.

There are several tools on the market to do this sort of thing.

You might try this one:

[ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.asp)

Comment: I have never used it to recover dropped tables, but the documentation supports the idea that it will do this.

Comment: by backing up, i actually meant making copies of the database and log files (as a backup) before trying anything. sql backup was not what i meant.

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody else has the same problem - Were you doing transaction log backups every X minutes?  If so, you can use Quest LiteSpeed's log reader or Quest Toad for SQL Server's log reader to read the log file backups.  It gives undo/redo scripts too for any transaction in the log backups or the ldf.

Answer (score 1):

And after that, look into using ApexSQLScript to script out your databases on a regular basis (and store in version control).

Answer (score 0):

yo do can!!
go to sql server managment studio,connect to your db, left click on your db and go to "tasks".
select restore -> database.
then click the "timeline" button and select 'especific date' and select the day before your mistake.
All programs that have access to your db mus be closed.
It worked for me, i had this very same probelm.